# Update TextViews outside an Activity Class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `viewPager` right below a `LinearLayout` (horizontal) which holds 6 `TextView`s.

This `LinearLayout` is a **status bar** which will hold all the player's stats, so it will be **updated very often**. That's why I decided to make a **method** to do just that: update the status bar.

### Issue

I need to update it, for instance, when the user purchases a Mine (which is a page of the `ViewPager`), but the code to listen to a player's tap on a page is in the `Adapter`. And when I try to insert a `TextView` on this Class, I just **cannot**.

> So I was wondering how I could make a method, accessible trough all my
>   classes, in order to refresh the values of those TextViews.

I have a **CenterRepository** Class, but it looks like I cannot add Android code in it, so I basically cannot add `TextView`s there.

---

[image]
[image]

---

### Code

Here's the **adapter**

```
public class MineAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private CenterRepository data;
private TextView expLvlTxt;
private TextView expTxt;
private TextView coinsTxt;

public MineAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    data = CenterRepository.getSingletonInstance();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {

    //Fill Data directly from Repository
    return data.getListOfLavels().size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    System.out.println("Code executed");

    final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.carousal_page, container,
            false);
```

#### [SKIPPED CODE]

```
// Unlock Button
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.unlockButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (data.getCurrentUser().getGold() >=
                    data.getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost()) {

                //If User can afford the purchase, remove lock image and buy it
                data.getListOfLavels().get(position).setUnlocked(true);

                data.getCurrentUser().setGold(
                        data.getCurrentUser().getGold()
                                - data.getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost()); // Update user's gold


                itemView.findViewById(R.id.unlockButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // Remove lock button
                itemView.findViewById(R.id.mineCost).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Reduced "
                        + data.getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                expLvlTxt.setText(String.valueOf(data.getCurrentUser().getExpLvl()));
                expTxt.setText(String.valueOf(data.getCurrentUser().getExp()));
                coinsTxt.setText(String.valueOf(data.getCurrentUser().getGold()));

            } else {

                // Not enough money
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not enough money to purchase You need " +
                        (data.getListOfLavels().get(position).getUnlockCost()
                                - data.getCurrentUser().getGold()) + " more", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

---

Here's the **Center Repository**

```
public class CenterRepository {

private User currentUser;
private static CenterRepository singletonInstance;
private ArrayList<Mine> minesList = new ArrayList<>();

private CenterRepository() {
}

public void addMine(Mine mine){
    minesList.add(mine);
}
public void setCurrentUser(User currentUser) {
    this.currentUser = currentUser;
}

public static CenterRepository getSingletonInstance() {
    if (null == singletonInstance) {
        singletonInstance = new CenterRepository();
    }
    return singletonInstance;
}
public User getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
}

public ArrayList<Mine> getListOfLavels() {
    return minesList;
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    return rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, there's no simple way to do it. Data binding an object to the view would ease the effort, though https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: So this is how you would do it? @cricket_007

Comment: I would at least try it with that library, yes. Alternatively, SharedPreferences might also work